# shared global variables in C

Tags: c, variables, linker, global-variables, scope

How can I create global variables that are shared in C? If I put it in a header file, then the linker complains that the variables are already defined. Is the only way to declare the variable in one of my C files and to manually put in `extern`s at the top of all the other C files that want to use it? That sounds not ideal.

Comment: Shared within your own source code? Put extern declaration in one header file, and definition in another (single) source. Those are shared among your process threads of course. For interprocess sharing of data, use IPC mechanisms (shared memory, pipes).

Comment: See also [What are `extern` variables in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/1433387#1433387)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I share variables between different .c files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045501/how-do-i-share-variables-between-different-c-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use extern to share variables between source files in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In the header file write it with `extern`.
And at the global scope of one of the c files declare it without `extern`.

Comment: Can we declare it in that *.c file's header file instead?

Answer (score 99):

In one header file (shared.h):

```
extern int this_is_global;
```

In every file that you want to use this global symbol, include header containing the extern declaration:

```
#include "shared.h"
```

To avoid multiple linker definitions, **just one declaration of your global symbol must be present across your compilation units** (e.g: shared.cpp) :

```
/* shared.cpp */
#include "shared.h"
int this_is_global;
```

Comment: do you have any preferred references to learn more about IPC mechanisms?

Comment: Please put more emphasis on "just one declaration of your global symbol..." Kind of tripped on that one. I had the declaration on all the c files I wanted to use the global variables on :(

Answer (score 22):

In the header file

header file

```
#ifndef SHAREFILE_INCLUDED
#define SHAREFILE_INCLUDED
#ifdef  MAIN_FILE
int global;
#else
extern int global;
#endif
#endif
```

In the file with the file you want the global to live:

```
#define MAIN_FILE
#include "share.h"
```

In the other files that need the extern version:

```
#include "share.h"
```

Comment: ah this is the solution i had a while ago - i forgot about the MAIN_FILE preprocessor variable. i thinik i like the cur accepted answer more tho

Answer (score 16):

You put the declaration in a header file, e.g.

```
 extern int my_global;
```

In one of your .c files you define it at global scope.

```
int my_global;
```

Every .c file that wants access to `my_global` includes the header file with the `extern` in.

Answer (score 6):

If you're sharing code between C and C++, remember to add the following to the `shared.h`file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern int my_global;
/* other extern declarations ... */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a cleaner way with just one header file so it is simpler to maintain.
In the header with the global variables prefix each declaration with a keyword (I use common) then in just one source file include it like this

```
#define common
#include "globals.h"
#undef common
```

and any other source files like this

```
#define common extern
#include "globals.h"
#undef common
```

Just make sure you don't initialise any of the variables in the globals.h file or the linker will still complain as an initialised variable is not treated as external even with the extern keyword. The global.h file looks similar to this

```
#pragma once
common int globala;
common int globalb;
etc.
```

seems to work for any type of declaration. Don't use the common keyword on #define of course.

Comment: You can also add `#ifndef common` `#define common extern` `#endif` to the header if you want to avoid defining common every time globals.h is included. The only caveat is that common is not undefined automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more elegant way to create global variables.

Just declare the variables as static inside a ".c" source file and create set/get functions.

The example below I use to override malloc, realloc and free functions during memory allocation tests.

Example:

memory-allocator.h

```
#ifndef MEMORY_ALLOCATOR_H_
#define MEMORY_ALLOCATOR_H_

#include <stddef.h>

void std_set_memory_allocators(void *(*malloc)(size_t size),
                               void *(realloc)(void *ptr, size_t size),
                               void (*free)(void *ptr));

void std_set_reset_allocators();

void *std_malloc(size_t size);

void *std_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);

void std_free(void *ptr);

#endif  // MEMORY_ALLOCATOR_H_
```

memory-allocator.c

```
#include "memory-allocator.h"

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    void *(*malloc)(size_t size);
    void *(*realloc)(void *ptr, size_t size);
    void (*free)(void *ptr);
} StdMemoryAllocator;

StdMemoryAllocator memory_allocators = {&malloc, &realloc, &free};

void std_set_memory_allocators(void *(*malloc)(size_t size),
                               void *(realloc)(void *ptr, size_t size),
                               void (*free)(void *ptr)) {
    memory_allocators.malloc = malloc;
    memory_allocators.realloc = realloc;
    memory_allocators.free = free;
}

void std_set_reset_allocators() {
    memory_allocators.malloc = malloc;
    memory_allocators.realloc = realloc;
    memory_allocators.free = free;
}

void *std_malloc(size_t size) {
    return memory_allocators.malloc(size);
}

void *std_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size) {
    return memory_allocators.realloc(ptr, size);
}

void std_free(void *ptr) {
    memory_allocators.free(ptr);
}
```

The struct `static struct StdMemoryAllocator_s memory_allocators` is started automatically when the application starts, and it point to the default C memory allocators.