# IAR Embedded Workbench : Unknown or ambiguous symbol

Tags: c, microcontroller, watch, stm32, iar

Solved.

I was trying to control the value of a variable in IAR Embedded Workbench (working with STM32F303xC microcontroller). I declared the variables in the library.h files as:

```
extern int my_variable1;
extern float another_variable //... etc
```

Then in library.c

```
int my_variable1 = 15;
float another_variable = 328.47;
```

In main.c

```
my_variable1 = 38;
another_variable = pow(10,2) + another_variable/8
```

But in watch, live watch and quick watch it rises the error : (column 1) Unknown or ambiguous symbol.

I wrote several programs with this IDE and the declaration of static variables worked and it allowed me to see the variable's value using the watches. In other programs i declared the variable as

```
int my_variable1;
```

In the main file, outside the main function and it worked too.

How can i solve this error?

As far as we go, it seems the the real question is:

There is a way to show in IAR Embedded Workbench the value of variables shared between .c-s?

Comment: What is the scope of declare static var into a header?..

Comment: In that way you can read only the .h and recognize all the variables and the function that this header provides.

Comment: There is no reason why you would ever declare variables in header files to begin with. Making a variable "global static" makes even less sense, it is like going to the paint store and asking for "white black" paint.

Comment: Moreover in this way you could share only the declarations in .h without sharing the .c files (and the source code)

Comment: global static is a sort of oxymoron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IDE Embedded Workbench, as form of optimization, doesn't allocate the variables that are declared but not used. So those  variables cannot be showed in the watches.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you declare the variable static.

This means you will have a discrete copies of those variable for each file that `#include` the hedaer file.

I guess that static watch work as far as you are breaking execution inside a specific function files. It will show you the local scoped copy of variable.

Comment: How should  I declare a variable that has to be used by more than one .c? As extern? (I have an error so, too)

Comment: @EagleOne Surely not static. `int var;` in the `.c` file. `extern int var;` into header file.

Comment: Question updated using answers from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045501/how-do-i-share-variables-between-different-c-files  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010647/shared-global-variables-in-c but still not working

Comment: @EagleOne Are each variable name used as unique in your project?

Comment: Yes. Declared as extern in lib.h, declared and defined in lib.c and used in some operation in main.c

Comment: @EagleOne What if you break inside a function that use one of those vars? Could you see the value in a standard watch view?

Comment: No values showed. After compilation, linking and flashing, when i start the program i can only see the error instead of the variable's value

Comment: The workbench gave me this error even trying to declare the variables only in main.c files as usual...

Comment: @EagleOne never happend to me. I worked a lot with that IDe without problem watching vars.

Comment: Finally got it. I had that problem only for few variables. Those variables were not modified. I think that the workbench, as optimization, doesn't allocate variables not used. Thanks. The problem is solved using the method i wrote above. Good work and have a nice day.