# Split program to .c files and .h files in C. Global variable issue

Tags: c, scope, global-variables, header-files

I wrote a c program with some global variables, and most functions use and modify those global variables. Then I decide to split this program into a c file and multiple header files. How do I deal with the global variables in the program?

Should I put them in the .c file? Or in the relevant .h files?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

Global variables are someway dangerous but in some cases we need them. try not to use global variables as a general tip. 
global variables can be declared in c file and externed in h file. 
for example:
lets assume that we declared in foo.c file global variable:

```
int g_variable = 0;
```

now in foo.h, we need to write

```
extern int g_variable;
```

for extending the scope of this variable for the whole program. now evrey h file that includes foo.h can access g_variable!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use the global variable in multiple places, use an `extern` global variable. See [Shared Global Variables in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010647/shared-global-variables-in-c).

If you only need it inside of a single `.c` file, then define it only in that `.c` file and mark it `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Global declarations should go in an .h file, e.g.:

h.h:

```
extern int x; //extern here means: declare x without reserving storage
```

and global definitions in a .c file, e.g.:

c.c:

```
#include "h.h" //to verify consistency
int x = 42; //reserve storage for x
```