# How do I share a global variable between c files?

Tags: c, extern

If I define a global variable in a `.c` file, how can I use the same variable in another `.c` file?

`file1.c`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i=10;

int main()
{
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

`file2.c`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //some data regarding i
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

How can the second file `file2.c` use the value of `i` from the first file `file1.c`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I share variables between different .c files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045501/how-do-i-share-variables-between-different-c-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use extern to share variables between source files in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

file 1:

```
int x = 50;
```

file 2:

```
extern int x;

printf("%d", x);
```

Comment: no, i didn't forget anything.  I'm just explaining what you would put in those files.

Comment: also, file 1 should NOT be a header file, it should be a .c file.  File 2 can be a header file which contains the "extern int x" part though.

Comment: @fresh_graduate: Putting the line `extern int x;` in a header file, and including that file from file2.c, has *exactly* the same effect as putting the line in file2.c. It's up to you how you organise your code, all you need is that after the preprocessor has finished with includes and everything else it does, file 2 has that line in it.

Comment: @steve..i can accept your comment as an answer.Knowing about extern,i can find it anywhere in the internet easily but was not able to understand the inclusion of files as how it is done.your comment above cleared everything thanks.Since i cannot accept a comment as an answer +1 for your comment.Nobody has clearly touched the point you mentioned here

Comment: Can I do the same with an array?

Comment: Please note that you don't have to use any includes in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `extern` keyword to declare the variable in the other `.c` file. E.g.:

```
extern int counter;
```

means that the actual storage is located in another file. It can be used for both variables and function prototypes.

Comment: Just for my education, could I see an example of a function prototype declaration using `extern`? Is it just as simple as putting `extern` before the prototype? (e.g., `extern void doSomething(int, char *);`)

Comment: @Platinum Azure: in C a function declaration is `extern` by default.  But it hurts nothing to add the `extern` explicitly, and it would be done just like in your example.

Answer (score 2):

using `extern <variable type> <variable name>` in a header or another C file.

Comment: but how should i include the files?is there no need for it?

Comment: @fresh_graduate: You need not include the file, linker will figure it out for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the second `.c` file use `extern` keyword with the same variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Do same as you did in file1.c
In file2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

extern int i;  /*This declare that i is an int variable which is defined in some other file*/

int main(void)
{
/* your code*/
```

If you use int i; in file2.c under main() then i will be treated as local auto variable not the same as defined in file1.c

Answer (score 1):

Use extern keyword in another .c file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use global variable i of file1.c in file2.c, then below are the points to remember:

1. main function shouldn't be there in file2.c
2. now global variable i can be shared with file2.c by two ways:
   a) by declaring with extern keyword in file2.c  i.e extern int i;
   b) by defining the variable i in a header file and including that header file in file2.c.

Comment: For 2. above, if you have two `.c` files and include the header, how many copies of the variable will there be in your program?

Answer (score 0):

use extern keyword in second while defining variable value of first c file.
//in first file
double z =50;

//in second file
extern double x;

Comment: Put `\`\`\`c`  (3 back-ticks and `'c'`) above your block of code and `\`\`\`` below it to format in a fixed font with `c` syntax highlight. (or indent all by 4-spaces). For code within a sentence, wrap in a single back-tick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).