# Undefined reference to global unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have three files:

```
TableGenerataor.h
TableGenerataor.cpp
Analyzer.cpp
```

I have declared unordered_map in TableGenerator.h and using that I create the object of unorderd_map in TableGenerataor.cpp.

```
map_t obj1;
data d;
```

TableGenerator.h

```
namespace N {

typedef std::tuple<int, char> key_t;

struct key_hash : public std::unary_function<key_t, std::size_t>
{
std::size_t operator()(const key_t& k) const
{
return std::get<0>(k) ^ std::get<1>(k) ;
}
};

struct key_equal : public std::binary_function<key_t, key_t, bool>
{
bool operator()(const key_t& v0, const key_t& v1) const
{
return (
std::get<0>(v0) == std::get<0>(v1) &&
std::get<1>(v0) == std::get<1>(v1) 
);
}
};

struct data
{
int AlertNo;

};

typedef std::unordered_map<const key_t,data,key_hash,key_equal> map_t;

}

enter code here
```

I want to use this unordered_map created in TableGenerator.cpp file in  Analyzer.cpp. I want to keep this unordered_map till the end of the program. For that purpose I want to make unordered_map global. Global seems to be better option rather than sending map as parameter to other function. I use the keyword extern in Analyzer.cpp.

extern map_t obj1;
extern data d;

but it still says that **undefined reference to obj1** when compiling. Please help me how do I make unorderd_map Global to make use of it in other cpp files. Secondly, is their any other better way to do this thing rather than making map global.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to to with the global being an `unordered_map`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I edited my question, while compiling it says undefined reference to obj1. This error I get when I link the object files.

Comment: My previous statement still holds.

Comment: To answer your second question, instead of making your variable global you could wrap it in a Singleton class http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3005167

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a syntax issue.

Consult these resources to see some examples:

- Short, sweet: [extern - How do I share a global variable between c files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6792967/3171324)
- Incredibly Detailed and Complete: [How do I share a variable between source files in C? With extern, but how?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/3171324)

Answer (score 0):

Are variables declarations in the same namespace as their definition? E.g. `N::obj1` might have been defined but`obj1` is referred to.

---

Original Answer:

You wrote in Analyzer.cpp:

```
extern map_t obj1;
extern data d;
```

So I assume you have

```
#include "TableGenerator.h"
```

in "Analyzer.cpp".

Move declarations of the two global variables to "TableGenerator.h". (Keep the definition of them in "TableGenerator.cpp".)

And try to access `N::obj1` and `N::d` in "Analyzer.cpp".