# Counting the number of function calls in an executable

Tags: c, ubuntu, function-call

I am trying to find the exact number of function calls to one of my implemented C function inside my code. The project includes several C files. What is the easiest solution to figure out how many times a function is called during the execution of the program? Specifically, I am interested to know how many times a specific function calls another function. For instance I have a C file like:

```
//file1.c
int main(){
foo1();
return 0;
}
```

and other C files like:

```
//file2.c
void  foo1(){
    foo2();
    ...
    foo2();
}
```

and

```
//file3.c
void foo2(){
    foo3();
    foo3();
    foo3();
}
```

Now I have my final executable `a.out` and want to know how many times `foo3()` is called inside `foo1()`. 
  BTW, I am compiling and running my project on Linux.

Comment: `foo3` called from other functions?

Comment: If you want to know this from within foo3, you can declare a static variable within foo3 that foo3 will increment on every call (a static variable declared within a function is automatically initialised to zero and retains its value from one call to the next). Otherwise, if you need to know this from anywhere in the program, declare a global variable that foo3 will increment on every call.

Comment: Do you need to code this or can you use an external tool for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 2 global variables (put [extern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6792967/2069380) at the places that access the variable outside the file you declare them) :

```
int foo1_active = 0;
int foo3_counter = 0;
```

then each time `foo1` is called you increment it variable and before the return you decrement it:

```
void foo1() {
    foo1_active++;
    ...
    foo1_active--;
    return
}
```

when `foo3` is called you check if `foo1` active and if it does you increment the counter:

```
void foo3() {
    if foo1_active > 0 { 
        foo3_counter++;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I defined the `foo3_counter` as `static int` in my main.c file, and also use `extern int foo3_counter` inside my file3.c, but I keep getting `undefined reference to 'foo3_counter'` inside my file3.c.

Comment: @A23149577 remove the `static`

Answer (score 1):

You have an ubuntu flag, so I assume you are using gcc. I'd strongly consider adding -pg to your CFLAGS and trying out [gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Implementation.html).

> Profiling works by changing how every function in your program is
>   compiled so that when it is called, it will stash away some
>   information about where it was called from. From this, the profiler
>   can figure out what function called it, and can count how many times
>   it was called. This change is made by the compiler when your program
>   is compiled with the `-pg' option, which causes every function to call
>   mcount (or _mcount, or __mcount, depending on the OS and compiler) as
>   one of its first operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can count function calls using a static variable instead of global variable.

```
int inc(){
    static int counter = 1;
    counter++;
    return counter;
}
int main(){
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d\n", inc());

    return 0;
}
```