# variable between files

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I share variables between different .c files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045501/how-do-i-share-variables-between-different-c-files)

If I have two source files, and one header: file1.c, file2.c, and header.h, and:

--header.h--

```
int i;
```

--file1.c--

```
#include <header.h>
i = 10;

int main() {
func();
return 0;
}
```

--file2.c--

```
#include <header.h>

void func() {
printf("i = %d\n", i);
return;
}
```

I get the warning that `i` defaults to an `int`. What could I do if I want to have `i` as a `float` for instance?

Comment: If I declare i as a float, I get the 'conflicting types' error.

Comment: Your `i = 10` is outside any function, so as such it is never executed. Instead, it is considered a variable definition that lacks a type, which the compiler fills in. However, to suggest a solution, I need to know what you are trying to achieve with this.

Answer (score 1):

Make it

```
extern int i;
```

in the header and

```
int i = 10;
```

in `file1.c`.

The warning means that for the (incomplete) declaration `i = 10;` in `file1.c`, the "implicit int" rule is applied, in particular, that line is interpreted as a declaration (since an assignment cannot appear outside function scope).

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors in your code. The first is that you *define* the variable `i` in the header file, which means that it will be defined in all source files that include the header. Instead you should *declare* the variable as `extern`:

```
extern int i;
```

The other problem is that you can't just assign to variables in the global scope in file1.c. Instead it's there that you should define the variable:

```
int i = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Declare** it as `extern` in the header (this means memory for it is reserved somewhere else):

```
/* header.h */
extern int i;
```

Then **define** it in only one `.c` file, i.e. actually reserve memory for it:

```
/* file1.c */
int i = <initial value>;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In the header use

   extern int i;
2. in either `file1.c` or `file2.c` have

   int i = 20;
3. If you want `float` just change `int` to `float`

Answer (score 0):

In 99.9% of all cases it is bad program design to share non-constant, global variables between files. There are very few cases when you actually need to do this: they are so rare that I cannot come up with any valid cases. Declarations of hardware registers perhaps.

In most of the cases, you should either use (possibly inlined) setter/getter functions ("public"), static variables at file scope ("private"), or incomplete type implementations ("private") instead.

In those few rare cases when you need to share a variable between files, do like this:

```
// file.h
extern int my_var;

// file.c
#include "file.h"
int my_var = something;

// main.c
#include "file.h"
use(my_var);
```

Never put any form of variable definition in a h-file.