# pass a value to another c file

Tags: c, variables, return-value

I have a `A.c` file that contains some `char*` variable `str1`.
I have a `B.c` file that contains some `f()` function, that make some transformation on a `char*` variable.

My point is: How can I pass the value of `str` to `B.c`, then compute the new string thanks to `f()`, and afterwards send back the new string value to `A.c` ?

Comment: Pass the string as an argument to the function.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's just crazy enough to work!

Comment: How you call the `f()` function? What you mean by 'send back'? Please explain and give more details. A code sample may help.

Comment: Example:
in A.c I have str1 = "hello"
I want to make a modification to str1 in B.c (str2 = str1 + "!")
After the modification, I want to send back the new value str2 to A.c

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045501/how-do-i-share-variables-between-different-c-files) too.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
// file: A.c

char* str1;
```

and

```
// file: B.c

extern char* str1;

void f(void)
{
  str1 = "blah";
}
```

Comment: How I get the new value in A.c ? and when I can get it?

Comment: `f()` directly modifies `str1`. When it returns, if it has changed the variable, the effect must be observable in `A.c`, `B.c` and everywhere.

Comment: So I have to call f() in A.c hein? and I will need a header file to compile the files or no ?

Comment: `char* str1` is a global variable, having a single copy. So any changes made to it are reflected immediately to any function accessing it.

Comment: This method makes the variable `str1` shared between the 2 source files. It means that it is the same variable whether it is referred in A.c or in B.c.

Comment: Perhaps you should add some text that advises against the use of global variables