# CODE is not executing in c++

Tags: c++

TASK 2 remains un-executed. Task 1 works fine, I input the yield values of the cows; but then the code stops running. A warning says that Herdtotalweek may be uninitialized. But I don't know how to fix that. There are no other warnings or errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() { //Task 1
  int Herdsize;
  int Day;
  float MilkYield1;
  float MilkYield2;
  int count;

  cout << "Please input herd size" << endl;
  cin >> Herdsize;
  while (Herdsize < 1 || Herdsize > 900) {
    cout << "Please re-input herdsize between 1 and 900" << endl;
    cin >> Herdsize;
  }

  int CowID[Herdsize + 1];
  float DailyYield[Herdsize * 7];
  float WeeklyYieldpercow[Herdsize * 14];

  for (count = 1; count < Herdsize + 1; count++) {
    cout << "Input 3 digit cow id ";
    cin >> CowID[count];
    while (CowID[count] < 1 || CowID[count] > 999) {
      cout << "Please re-input cow a 3 digit cow id " << endl;
      cin >> CowID[count];
    }

    for (Day = 1; Day < 8; Day++) {
      cout << "Please input first milk yield of cow,day";
      cout << Day;
      cout << endl;
      cin >> MilkYield1;
      cout << "Please input second milk yield day:";
      cout << Day;
      cout << ",  if there is a second yield if not enter 0";
      cout << endl;
      cin >> MilkYield2;
    }
    DailyYield[((count - 1) * 7) + Day] = MilkYield1 + MilkYield2;
    WeeklyYieldpercow[count] = WeeklyYieldpercow[count] +
      DailyYield[((count - 1) * 7) + Day];
  }


  // TASK 2
  int count2 = 1;
  float Herdtotalweek;
  float Averagevolume;
  for (count = 1; count2 < Herdsize + 1; count++) {
    Herdtotalweek = Herdtotalweek + WeeklyYieldpercow[count];
  }
  Averagevolume = Herdtotalweek / Herdsize;
  int Herdtotalweekwhole = int(Herdtotalweek + 0.5);
  int Averagevolumewhole = int(Averagevolume + 0.5);
  cout << "Total weekly volume=";
  cout << Herdtotalweekwhole;
  cout << "Average volume =";
  cout << Averagevolumewhole;
}
```

Comment: my eyes are bleeding looking at your code .. lol .. At least format it.

Comment: is your enter key broken?

Comment: Sorry for the messy code.

Comment: Please provide a minimal input example that triggers the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to uninitialized variables? C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987901/what-happens-to-uninitialized-variables-c)

Comment: No. Enter key is fine. It enters the first inputs but doesn't execute task 2

Comment: You can edit the post to make the formatting more readable.  If you don't, then most people (including me) will just not even attempt to read it.  You especially need to get the indentation right when there are nested looops.

Comment: I assigned it 0 later still doesn't work.

Comment: What inputs do you give (including when you press enter? This will help me try to reproduce your problem. What do you get on the screen? What does "stops running" mean?

Comment: herdsize= 2 ,  id=001,all first yields=2.9 all second yields=3 for first cow

Comment: and id=002 and all first yields= 3 and second= 4

Comment: @AloysiusRebeiro Somebody took the time to make your code readable, please don't mess it up again.

Comment: @AloysiusRebeiro please [edit] your question and put the input _there_. And don't mess up the code formatting which I just did for you. And don't describe the input, just show it verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `float Herdtotalweek;` try using `float Herdtotalweek = 0;` ?

also, in your second for statement, instead of `for (count=1;count2<Herdsize+1;count++)` try `for (count=1;count<Herdsize+1;count++)` (you were using count2 instead of count, which was probably a copy/paste error)

Answer (score 1):

The for loop after task2 never completes. It is an infinite loop as you are not updating count2.