# Share global variable between .c file

Tags: c, global-variables, declaration

Hi I just wondering how to Share global variable between .c file.
I try to add follow code, but still get error.

test.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max = 50;
int main() 
{
  printf("max %d", max); // result max 50
}
```

pass.h

```
extern int max;
```

passed.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pass.h"

max;

int main()
{    
    printf("pass %d \n", max);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile passed.c I get follow error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_max", referenced from:
  _main in passed-iOMugx.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone help? Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you really mean to have two main() functions?

Comment: Why do you have two main functions?  Are they separate programs or are they meant to be linked together into one program?  If they are being linked together in one program it shouldn't have complained about max - it should have complained about duplicate main functions.

Comment: Yes, I know it might impossible to do

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I share variables between different .c files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045501/how-do-i-share-variables-between-different-c-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the variable in a header file, e.g. let's say in declareGlobal.h-

```
//declareGlobal.h
extern int max;
```

Then you should define the variable in one and only file, e.g. let's say, test.c. Remember to include the header file where the variable was declared, e.g. in this case, declareGlobal.c

```
//test.c
#include "declareGlobal.h"
int max = 50;
```

You can then use this variable in any file- just remember to include the header file where it's declared (i.e. declareGlobal.c), for example, if you want to use it in passed.c, you can do the following:

```
//passed.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "declareGlobal.h"
#include "test.c"
int main()
{
printf("pass %d \n", max);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include "declareGlobal.c"` - just **don't.**

Comment: @H2CO3 I actually meant `declareGlobal.h`

Comment: Apologies, you also need to include the test.c (where max is actually defined and initialized) file in passed.c. Edited my answer to reflect the change.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have *two* programs, and data (like variables) can not be shared that simply between programs.

You might want to read about [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) and other [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) methods.

---

If on the other hand you only want to have *one* program, and use a variable defined in another file, you still are doing it wrong. You can only have one `main` function in a single program, so remove the `main` function from one of the source files. Also in `pass.c` the expression `max;` does nothing and you don't need it.

Then pass both files when compiling, like

```
$ clang -Wall -g test.c pass.c -o my_program
```

After the above command, you will (hopefully) have an executable program named `my_program`.