# How to share one variable between 2 .c files?

Tags: c, extern, os161

Consider a variable abulo. I am trying to share abulo between 2 .c files. Here is what I did --

1. Created a.h . This file contains the line,
   extern int abulo;
2. a.c contains a statement like this,
   int abulo = 0;
3. in b.c, a.h has been included. Then there is just a kprintf function printing the value of yours.

But when I try to run the code it shows me an output like this --

```
undefined reference to `abulo'
```

Tried to use the idea of the accpeted answer given here - [How do I share variables between different .c files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045501/how-do-i-share-variables-between-different-c-files)

what am I doing wrong here ? How to get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should link `a.o` when building the executable.
Example:

```
cc -c a.c
cc -c b.c
cc a.o b.o -o executable
#  ^^^ this is important
```