# pass MySQL connection to c function or use it globally

Tags: c, mysql-connector-c

I want to create MySQL connection in one function (file) in a C project and then use that connection globally (access it in every function or file in the project). Is that possible and what is the logic (pattern) I should follow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced in MySQL but presumably the connection is stored in a variable after you make it, perhaps a MYSQL*. Therefore, you can just use the standard way to share global variables across files in C. See: [How do I share variables between different .c files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045501/how-do-i-share-variables-between-different-c-files) , [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)